# How to allow blank space in firstname filed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery validation, i just want to validate  form field "First name" which allow only characters and blank space.

```
for eg:
"aaa bbb" instead of "aaabbb"
```

Comment: if you wont like questions then please need not to give answers, but dont reduce my reputations....

Comment: @naveedkhan - I didn't down vote your question but you should [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) on reputation.

Comment: @naveedkhan I haven't reduced it either, but what have you tried? There is also very useful web-site www.google.com. Have you tried it at least? Do you have the code that's failing? or anything?

Comment: I downvote your question because it's very low quality since you don't put enough effort into your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can you [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) or regex as following:

```
$("yourinputselector").each(function(){
    if (/^[a-zA-Z]+\s$/.test(this.value)) {
        // valid input value
    } else {
        // invalid input value
    }
}
```